# Android Facebook SDK lets users not log in?

Tags: android, facebook

I have a screen that popups up that Facebook login thing with the following code:

```
    //facebook stuff
    if (Session.getActiveSession() == null ||  Session.getActiveSession().isClosed()) {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, null);
    }
```

If the user hits the "back" button and dismisses the login thing, it automatically sends them to the screen that was supposed to be facebook protected (and has errors because no user is logged in).

How should I handle this?  I see that in the old sdk or whatever, it had:

```
facebook.isSessionValid()
```

Is there still a way to do this? If so, HOW would I actually do it?  Some sort of while loop until they finally stop trying to back out?  Is there a way to disable backing out of that screen? I don't generate that screen at all: facebook does. Is this just a bug I have to live with?

Edit:

Corollary to this is that I have just noticed that if I use the facebook app to logout, the facebook sdk doesn't tell me this in my own app: It still authenticates.  Even worse is when it does it even after I have logged out, then logged in as an entirely different user using the facebook app.  How do I handle this?

Edit: More Code

This is now how I log in to facebook (in the Activity's onCreate) and ask to get my graph user and my friends'  (gets me first, then once that asynch thing is done, gets friends)

```
if (Session.getActiveSession() == null ||  Session.getActiveSession().isClosed()) {
            Log.v(CLASS_NAME, "Logging into facebook");
            //Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.statusCallback());
            final Session.StatusCallback sessionStatusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(exception != null)
                    {
                        // Handle fail case here.
                        Log.v(CLASS_NAME, "Facebook login error " + exception);
                        return;
                    }

                    // If session is just opened...
                    if(state == SessionState.OPENED)
                    {
                        // Handle success case here.
                        Log.v(CLASS_NAME, "Facebook login success!");
                        return;
                    }


            }

        };

        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, sessionStatusCallback);
    }


    //annonymous inner class
    final Callback<ArrayList<GraphUser>> inner_callback_class2 = new FacebookHelper.Callback<ArrayList<GraphUser>>() {
        @Override
        public void setResult(ArrayList<GraphUser> result) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(GraphUser user : result){
                friends.put(user.getId(), user);
            }
            friends.put(me.getId(), me); //i can see my own comments as well


            //get comments
            //ArrayList<String>tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
            //tmp.add("Jenny");
            //tmp.add("Charles");
            //initial comment call so I can view them
            //
            getComments();
        }
    };


    //annonymous inner class
    FacebookHelper.Callback<GraphUser> inner_callback_class = new FacebookHelper.Callback<GraphUser>() {
        @Override
        public void setResult(GraphUser result) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            me = result;
            Log.v("ANYTHING", me.getName());
            //make sure i have an id before I do anything
            FacebookHelper.getMyFriends(Session.getActiveSession(),inner_callback_class2);
            //post comment
            //RailsServerHelper.postComment("Comment Testing", movie.id, myID, currentNPT);
        }
    };

    FacebookHelper.getMyID(Session.getActiveSession(), inner_callback_class);
```

This is how I get my friends (in a static helper class):

```
public static void getMyFriends(final Session session, final Callback<ArrayList<GraphUser>> callback){
    Request request = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList<GraphUser> tmp = new ArrayList<GraphUser>(users);
            try {
                callback.setResult(tmp);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    request.executeAsync(); 

}
```

The only other facebook thing I have is that whole clear the session thing you suggested:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    Log.v(CLASS_NAME, "Clearing facebook session");
    pleaseStop = true;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

It won't let me log back in at all.  I have two devices I'm testing it on.

The first device was working fine originally with one profile, but when I tried to try a second profile it wouldn't log the first one out, so I did that closeAndClearTokenInformation() thing.  That resulted in NO profile, and it won't pop up the whole facebook log in stuff anymore.  I think there is no profile because it always prints out "Logging into facebook", and the getMe call thing never works. (Just from describing my code here I see I can put the getMe stuff in the facebook log in callback, though) It also never prints the success statement I put in the callBack, and on the first device it prints out the error statement if I hit the back button (no matter how long I sit at that screen).

The second device never managed to get a profile logged in because the back button was hit on the login screen.  Ever since that, the system seems to think its "logged in" as nobody, and nothing I do can get it to refresh.  I don't ever see it attempting to log in like the first device. The closeAndClear call thing seems to do nothing on this device.  If relevant, the second device is a virtual simulator running on an entirely different machine.

On the actual device, what I see is:

```
01-24 07:16:04.669: V/MakeAndViewCommentsActivity(3677): Logging into facebook
```

And then a bunch of system messages (I waited over ten minutes), none of which seem to have warnings or errors, and then:

```
01-24 07:29:05.548: V/MakeAndViewCommentsActivity(3677): Clearing facebook session
01-24 07:29:05.552: V/MakeAndViewCommentsActivity(3677): Facebook login error com.facebook.FacebookException: Log in attempt aborted.
```

Why isn't the facebook openActiveSession ever returning?

Edit: The facebook sample apps still have the original log in working, but don't care if I log out or change users in the actual facebook app.  I guess they don't include any session clearing either?

Edit:  When I have a print statement of:

```
Log.v(CLASS_NAME, "Facebook callback with state: " + state);
```

I see:

```
01-24 09:10:54.333: V/MakeAndViewCommentsActivity(4869): Facebook callback with state: OPENING
```

does the callback only get called once?  Or is it going to be theoretically called again with a state of "OPEN" if it completes?

### SOLUTION:

Edit: Looking up the fact that it never leaves the "OPENING" state helped me a lot, it turns out I had to add the code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession()
        .onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

And then it just worked!  I have no idea why. I guess I will do research on this, but I"m glad I can finally change users.

Comment: The last one, the code of `onActivityResult` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in a null callback. If you implemented the callback, you would see that the callback would be called, and if you checked state.isClosed(), it would return true (and the state should be CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED). There should also be an exception in the exception parameter. You cannot disable the ability for users to back out of SSO, that's by design.

You're also correct in that there are no notifications if the user logs out of the facebook app. One way to have a better user experience is to always display the user's name and profile picture when you're doing something on behalf of the user (like posting a status), so it's immediately obvious that it's not the correct user. The other options is to always call session.closeAndClearTokenInformation every time your app exits. This way, you're always starting a fresh session, and if the user has the facebook app installed, it's still a very fast auth (no additional buttons to press). The drawback is that if they don't have the facebook app, then it will pop up a web dialog for login every time (but you can probably work around that by checking for the existence of the FB app).

Comment: When I try calling closeAndClearTokenInformation in my activity onDestroy method, it seems to clear the session (according to debug statements) but I am never given the opportunity to log in, or even approve the auth, even if I back out of the app entirely.

Comment: I am also very confused: I thought the Facebook SDK tapped into a phone global Session variable. That is, if you are logged out in one app, you are logged out in all apps. This seems a LOT less useful than what I had imagined.

Comment: If you've already authorized the app, AND you have the facebook app installed, AND it's still the same user logged into the FB app, then the next time you auth again, there will be no pop up (it just assumes that you haven't revoked the auth - which you can do either via the FB app, or at facebook.com). The Active Session is only global to your app, and not global to the phone.

Comment: even after logging out and logging in as a different user via the facebook app, MY app is still not prompting me to login, or authorize, or logging in at all.  Pretty discouraging.  The callback I added doesn't get called unless I back out of the activity (clearing the session), and then it just says that the log in attempt was aborted.  Why would it be hanging like this? My phone clearly can get to facebook if the fb app is working...

Comment: Can you post some more code please, I think the problem may be elsewhere in your integration with the SDK.

Comment: AH!  I need to override onActivityResult for some reason!  Now it works, thank you!

Comment: The reason you need to override onActivityResult is because the login workflow passes back some data (like the access token), which needs to be passed back into the Session. Since the login workflow starts a new Activity using startActivityForResult, the only way to pass back information is via onActivityResult.

Comment: @MingLi i guess their is a bug in facebook sdk 3.0.1, when i login from non activity, the onActivityResult never get called?

Comment: @Muhammad Babar That's not a bug.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar it's not a bug, it's by design. You must call login from an Activity or Fragment.